# JPA concurrent updates on tree nodes lead to transaction deadlocks

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, tree

I support a real world java application (web service) which provides some sort of file system to it's clients. All the metadata of the individual file system trees is kept in the database. Now when *"too many"* concurrent updates happen on a given tree the underlying database transactions run into a deadlock situation due to implicit row level write locks.

I cross-read [Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties](http://amzn.com/0123877334) and what the given entity model results in is the simplest case of how to represent a tree in SQL, called a **adjacency list**. As much as I like Mr. Celko's nested set pattern, I fear this won't be easy to implement in JPA and even then frequent insertions would lead to a lot of data reorganization overhead.

The database in use is MySQL and the used libraries include Spring-Data-JPA and Hibernate 4.1.7.

As the original code is quite complicated I extracted a minimal test case. Have a look below.

This is the entity that represents a tree node:

```
@Entity
public class Node extends AbstractPersistable<Integer> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Node.class);

    @ManyToOne
    private Node parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Node> children = new LinkedHashSet<Node>();

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentInstantAsMillisLong")
    private Instant timeStamp = Instant.now();

    @Version
    private Long version;

    public Node addChild(Node child) {
        child.setParent(this);
        children.add(child);
        touch();
        return this;
    }

    public void touch() {
        doTouch(Instant.now());
    }

    private void doTouch(Instant time) {
        logger.info("touching {} to {}", this, time);
        this.timeStamp = time;
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.doTouch(time);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my test case to simulate concurrent updates on the tree:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SpringConfig.class)
public class NodeServiceIntegrationTest {

    @Inject
    private NodeRepository repository;

    @Inject
    private NodeService service;

    private Random random;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.random = new Random();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRecursiveUpdate() throws Exception {
        int depth = random.nextInt(10) + 1;
        Node root = new Node();
        final Node leaf = createHierarchy(root, depth);
        root = repository.save(root);

        int threadCount = 50;
        Callable<Node> addChild = new Callable<Node>() {
            @Override
            public Node call() throws Exception {
                return service.addChild(leaf.getId(), new Node());
            }
        };
        List<Callable<Node>> tasks = Collections.nCopies(threadCount, addChild);
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
        List<Future<Node>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
        List<Node> resultList = new ArrayList<Node>(futures.size());
        for (Future<Node> future : futures) {
            resultList.add(future.get());
        }
        // todo assert something... ;)
    }

    private Node createHierarchy(Node root, int depth) {
        int count = random.nextInt(20) + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Node child = new Node();
            root.addChild(child);
            if (depth > 0 && random.nextBoolean()) {
                return createHierarchy(child, depth - 1);
            }
        }
        return Iterables.get(root.getChildren(), count - 1);
    }

}
```

This provoces the same error I see in the production code too:

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:639)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:516)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:394)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at a.e.treetest.service.NodeService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$98fc01a8.addChild(<generated>)
    at a.e.treetest.service.NodeServiceIntegrationTest$1.call(NodeServiceIntegrationTest.java:54)
    at a.e.treetest.service.NodeServiceIntegrationTest$1.call(NodeServiceIntegrationTest.java:51)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

So my question is whether there is a better way to represent trees in a SQL-Database and what would be a good way to support frequent insertions without provoking dead locks. Or is it that I have to accept that on concurrent updates dead locks may happen and I should look into automatically retrying the original operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [Nested Set Model](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2013/01/tree-in-sql-database-nested-set-model.html) - I've never run into deadlock problems with it

[Hibernate implementation](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/nested-set-implementation)

Comment: I'm in the middle of an implementation attempt based on the link you posted. As there seem to be no more answers coming in I will accept yours untested. Thank you.